# "Failed to Find Audience for Journey" - SFMC Error Message

Tags: marketing-cloud, error-messages, distributed-marketing

I am trying to create a Distributed Marketing journey/template. I am getting this error, "Failed to find audience selected in this journey". I tried to update/recreate my DE but that didn't resolve it. Anyone know how to troubleshoot this error? Thank you in advance!

[image: Audience Failed]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the question above I found the answer -> the template I used had issues. I created a new DE, from an existing template (from a journey already in the DM queue and the error was resolved. I also updated the settings to reentry only after exiting.